# <Response [403]> to login zalando

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests, request, http-status-code-403

[This is what it looks like to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZZcm.png)  |  I am working on this project to connect to zalando but I am encountering this error, I really don't understand how to fix it, would someone please tell me how I could fix it and successfully connect?

```
def login():

    headers = {
        'authority': 'accounts.zalando.com',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9',
        'referer': 'https://accounts.zalando.com/authenticate?sales_channel=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&passwordMeterFT=true',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    }

    url = 'https://zalando.com/api'

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    #print(r.cookies.get_dict())
    #print(r.headers)


    headers = {
        'authority': 'accounts.zalando.com',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
        'accept-language': 'fr-FR,fr;q=0.9',
        'cookie': r.headers['Set-Cookie'],
        'referer': 'https://accounts.zalando.com/authenticate?sales_channel=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&passwordMeterFT=true',
        'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="109", "Chromium";v="109"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'x-csrf-token': r.cookies.get_dict()['Zalando-Client-Id'],
        'x-flow-id': r.headers['X-Zalando-Child-Request-Id']
    }

    params = {
        'email': 'xxx',
        'secret': 'xxxXXXXXXXXX',
    }

    response = requests.post('https://accounts.zalando.com/api/login', json=params, headers=headers)
    print(response.content)
    print(response.json())
    print(response.cookies.get_dict())
    print(response.headers)
    


login()
```

Comment: Are you able to connect in a regular browser?

Comment: In general, a 403 response means that the server decided it doesn't want to serve your request, for reasons other than a bad username/password.  Perhaps it didn't like your IP address, or it didn't like the request headers, or you've made too many requests, or some other reason.

Comment: Your only real option is to make your python request look _identical_ to the same request from your browser.  Same IP address, same headers, same user-agent, same _everything_.

Comment: I use proxies but I still have the same mistake @JohnGordon